# How to tally column values of multiple rows with pure mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

hypothetic tables

`user_id | hits`

Can I get MySQL to return the total hits of a Select query? I know i could add them together with php or similar, just wondering if there is a pure MySQL way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Total hits per user

 SELECT userId, Sum(Hits)
 FROM Table
 GROUP by userId

 OR 

 Total hits

 SELECT Sum(Hits)
 FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(hits) from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific SQL query you're using you could either [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) a column or potentially use the '[WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)' GROUP modifier if you require a query-wide total.